# Substitute spelt for white flour

Tags: bread, flour

I heard Spelt flour is lighter and easier to digest. Can I substitute spelt for white flour in my standard white bread recipe that I make all the time? Or, do I need a spelt specific recipe?

What kind of dough does spelt flour make? Is it very sticky? Hard to work with? Any tips to keep in mind before giving this a shot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Info about spelt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30363/info-about-spelt)

Comment: No. Thanks for posting, that's more about the nutritional spelt information. My question is focused on the practical ways to use Spelt flour.

Comment: did you read the answers?

Comment: They're nice info about spelt but not what I'm looking for. The answer below is much more on target...

Comment: The problem is, the answer below is incomplete, because it doesn't address the gluten issue, which seems like it would be an issue for you.  I still contend the question is a duplicate, and that the original question can be added to.

Comment: No - actually this has totally nothing to do with gluten. I didn't mention gluten and am not looking to go gluten free. I've heard that many non celiac people find spelt easier to digest. Question is different than the one you suggested and answer is totally different than those answers. This answer was actually very helpful. I really appreciate the time you took to investigate for me and care you invest to keep our site with high quality questions. Keep it up!

Comment: The point is not about being gluten free.  The point is that white and spelt flour have different gluten and protein contents.  They cannot be substituted 1:1 without impacting your final product.  Do you prefer the answer you want to hear, or an answer that will inform your decision on how best to make the substitution?  I agree that my proposed duplicate is incomplete, but the answer below is inaccurate.  A 100% spelt flour dough will behave differently from a 100% white flour dough.  ...but good luck.  I hope you have success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelt can be substituted 1:1 for whole wheat flours to generate about the same characteristics in the final product.

I'd say spelt bread is more coarse, and tastes like grain, but there's a matter of preference and perception on that.

Recipes calling for white flour have overshadowing variables and variations, so trying with a blend and seeing how you like the result is the way to come to your answer... Try making a batch with half of the flour replaced and a quarter of the flour replaced and see if you like what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the answer from Phil. Spelt flour has more gliadin and less glutenin than wheat flour. (See Escarnot *et al*, [Reactivity of gluten proteins from spelt and bread wheat accessions towards A1 and G12 antibodies in the framework of celiac disease](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0308814618310677).) One would expect this to affect the gluten formation in bread.

My experience is that substituting wheat flour for spelt flour makes for a 'cakier' loaf. That is, the loaf is softer, less structured, and less chewy. All this suggests less gluten formation.